# ListView items not completely loaded using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.listview

My List View controller doesn't load all the elements, just it loads 1 element in this case, in other cases it loads like 4 but the others don't

As I have test where the problem occurs i have known that the problem is over the Frame controller, thanks to the frame most of my items on  my List View dont load

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <Frame
          HeightRequest="100"
          Margin="10"
          HasShadow="True"
          CornerRadius="25"
          BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid
            Padding="5">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Text="{Binding Name}"
              FontAttributes="Bold"
              FontSize="Large"
              HorizontalOptions="Start"
              VerticalOptions="Start">
          </Label>
          <Image
              HeightRequest="50"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Source="{Binding TaskIcon}"
              HorizontalOptions="End"
              VerticalOptions="Start">
          </Image>
          <Label
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Text="{Binding Description}"
              FontAttributes="Bold"
              FontSize="Medium"
              HorizontalOptions="Start"
              VerticalOptions="End">
          </Label>
          <Button
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Text="{Binding IsDone}"
              TextColor="White"
              FontAttributes="Bold"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="Center"
              FontSize="Small"
              CornerRadius="100"
              BackgroundColor="LawnGreen">
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Frame>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The results as i have mentioned are the incomplete load of my items as the following image shows:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[Edited]
I have edited my code as the following and the error is still the same

```
<ListView
               SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TasksCollection}"
                    GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
                    HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell
                                Text="{Binding Key}"
                                TextColor="White"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Frame
                                    HeightRequest="150"
                                    Margin="10"
                                    HasShadow="True"
                                    CornerRadius="25"
                                    BackgroundColor="White">
                                    <Grid
                                        Padding="5">
                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GridExpandCommand}"/>
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start">
                                        </Label>
                                        <Image
                                            HeightRequest="25"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Source="{Binding TaskIcon}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start">
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            Text="{Binding Description}"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                            VerticalOptions="End">
                                        </Label>
                                        <Button
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Text="{Binding IsDone}"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            CornerRadius="100"
                                            BackgroundColor="LawnGreen">
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: If you remove the `Frame` are the List of items shown as you expect?

Comment: @pinedax yes, i don’t know why

Comment: @AndrésQuirozValdovinos , my answer told you exactly that and why, but you deny it and don't show the code that you say to resolve that problem, so I think this needs to be closed as it is not reproducible.

Comment: @IvanIčin i have updated my code, i forgot something important, is that i was using the grouping option

Comment: @Andrés Quiroz, did you solved your issue now, if yes, please remember to mark the helpful reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen only if your layout cannot fit (aside from trivial issue that you are sending the empty data which you would probably see), you are trying to fit too big items into too little space. You should set the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` of images, and possibly you also need to set `LineBreakMode` for labels.

Comment: i have done that as in my code is shown, but that didnt do anything, any other option please?

Comment: @AndrésQuirozValdovinos you haven't - your layout obviously can't fit - your frame is 100 height (maximum if fits), it has the padding and two same rows where you want to set image of 50 height. It can't fit for sure, do the maths :).

Comment: I have done it in my code (not in the shown below, in my actual code) but the problem is still the same, i have increase the height of my frame and minimize the height of my layout and the problem is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I set ListView **HasUnevenRows="True"**, and it works fine and don't have any issue.

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame
                            Margin="10"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            CornerRadius="25"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            HeightRequest="120">
                            <Grid Padding="5">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Large"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Image
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Source="{Binding TaskIcon}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                <Button
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    BackgroundColor="LawnGreen"
                                    CornerRadius="100"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Small"
                                    Text="{Binding IsDone}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have set the property HasUnevenRows to true and the problem is still, also I have updated my post with more codes you want to check it out

Comment: Can you provide one sample that can reproduce your issue at github, I will download your sample to test.